# Angular Material switch with C3.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, dashboard, angular-material, c3.js

I use Angular Material in combination with [C3.js](http://c3js.org/) and I'm trying to replace default C3 legend with the Angular Material switch component. 
It works good after the first page load, but it doesn't work [after refreshing (reloading) page](http://recordit.co/DKMuysijB0). Please take a look at the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zhOwHnHdXDh1UryJzxfz?p=preview)

```
app.controller('GraphCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    data1: true,
    data2: true
  };

  // grid lines
  var chart_grid_lines = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart1',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ],
      type: 'spline'
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    }
  });

  $scope.updateChart = function() {
        if ($scope.data.data1)
            $scope.chart_grid_lines.show(['data1']);
        else
            $scope.chart_grid_lines.hide(['data1']);
        if ($scope.data.data2)
            $scope.chart_grid_lines.show(['data2']);
        else
            $scope.chart_grid_lines.hide(['data2']);
  };
});
```

Does anyone know whether we talking about angular material bug here?

Comment: Does http://jsfiddle.net/vog1cnv2/ too have the same problem? This is the one with $watch. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @potatopeelings, only this fiddle works fine every time I refresh. I'm trying to find out why it doesn't work on my project (Chrome, Opera, FF, IE) and on the plunker. I'll try to update the version of the angular material and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, upgrading to AMD 0.10.1 has not helped :(

Comment: does it trigger the updateChart or watch?

Comment: I tried with both methods, the same thing happens